# Is it possible to modify the html file placed on server directly

Tags: html

I have one doubt in my mind. Is it possible to modify the html file placed on server directly by accessing its URL eg. www.abc.com/test.html. The same way we can read it directly.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java.

Comment: If you could, just imaging the security issues.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to login with an ftp client to modify it. The closest you could get is to use Google Chrome and use the developer mode to add text temporarily until the page gets reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No.
when you are opening the page like this - www.abc.com/test.html, you are actually sending a request to the server in HTTP protocol. Which just load a response html from the server. If you want to edit a page from the sever directly you must use a FTP client s/w.
Developer edition of any browser will help you only to edit those files temporarily and then you have to save it locally and again upload it to the server.
I would like to suggest you to use a proper FTP Client instead like FileZilla.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with java or java-ee so please remove those tags.

Answer (score 1):

NO, it cannot be. At least not using normal methods that is via web browser. Web browser only renders the page.

But if you use tools like FTP and others through which you can modify the contents of the file then it can be done.

It also does not mean that you can not write on a file or create a file on server via web browser. If there is proper write access given on that file or directory then it can be done via browsers.